# How would I best normalize the pd MultiIndex df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a PD df that is MultiIndex. I would like to run a function over each symbol but am running the normalizing function over full d. The first symbol is good but the symbols that follow are getting manipulated by the first symbol. How would I normalize with vectorization rather than iterating over the symbol and filtering each?

This is what I tried when I didn't have a MultiIndex df and only one symbol.

`>>>df.loc['Adj_Close_Norm'] = df/df.iloc[0]`

```
>>>print(df)
                    Adj_Close_Price
Symbol Date
JPM    2010-01-04            40.87
       2010-01-05            41.67
       2010-01-06            41.89
       2010-01-07            42.72
       2010-01-08            42.62
...                            ...
SPY    2011-12-23           125.19
       2011-12-27           125.29
       2011-12-28           123.64
       2011-12-29           124.92
       2011-12-30           124.31

[1008 rows x 1 columns]
>>>df.loc['Adj_Close_Norm'] = df/df.iloc[0] 

>>>print(df)
                   Adj_Close_Price  Adj_Close_Norm
Symbol Date
JPM    2010-01-04            40.87        1.000000
       2010-01-05            41.67        1.019574
       2010-01-06            41.89        1.024957
       2010-01-07            42.72        1.045265
       2010-01-08            42.62        1.042819
...                            ...             ...
SPY    2011-12-23           125.19        3.063127
       2011-12-27           125.29        3.065574
       2011-12-28           123.64        3.025202
       2011-12-29           124.92        3.056521
       2011-12-30           124.31        3.041595

[1008 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `groupby` + `transform`

```
df.loc['Adj_Close_Norm']=df['Adj_Close_Price']/df.groupby(level=0)['Adj_Close_Price'].transform('first')
```